# Rails 5 Custom Controller Action for CSV Export

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, http-status-code-404, controllers

I am using Ruby's built in CSV functionality to export some tables as csv files. It all works fine if I am in the

```
def index
// code
end
```

However, I have a custom action in the controller called 'annual' with a 'respond_to block as follows:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @surveys }
  format.csv { send_data @surveys.to_csv, filename: "survey-annual-#{Date.today}.csv" }
end
```

The error is:

```
"status":404,"error":"Not Found","exception":"#\u003cActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Survey with 'id'=annual\u003e","traces":{"Application Trace":[{"id":1,"trace":"app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb:34:in `show'"}]
```

I don't believe this is specific to .csv as .json produces the same error. I am wondering if defining a method '.to_csv' in the model is causing a problem because of Ruby class structure; I'm not good enough with Ruby and haven't been able to find an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Which line is app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb:34. It says it's in show and you posted the index method

Comment: How is it looking for Survey.id="annual\u003e".Where is @surveys being declared?

Answer (score 0):

Its actually a very basic and common routing error and has nothing to do with CSV generation. Check the logs if you don't belive me.

Routes in Rails have priority in the order they are defined. So if you for example have declared your routes as:

```
resources :surveys
get 'surveys/annual', to: 'surveys#annual'
```

The request for `surveys/annual` will always be passed to `SurveysController#show` as it matches first.

Routes are just superpowered regexes. So the `GET /surveys/:id` route does not merely look for integer ids.

Rather the following will match:

```
/surveys/1
/surveys/foo
/surveys/foo%20bar%20baz
```

But not `/surveys/foo/bar` or `POST /surveys/foo`.

To add additional restful actions properly you should instead use a block and the `collection` option:

```
resources :surveys do
  get :annual, on: :collection
end
```

This adds the route in the correct order as seen below:

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
annual_surveys GET    /surveys/annual(.:format)   surveys#annual
       surveys GET    /surveys(.:format)          surveys#index
               POST   /surveys(.:format)          surveys#create
    new_survey GET    /surveys/new(.:format)      surveys#new
   edit_survey GET    /surveys/:id/edit(.:format) surveys#edit
        survey GET    /surveys/:id(.:format)      surveys#show
               PATCH  /surveys/:id(.:format)      surveys#update
               PUT    /surveys/:id(.:format)      surveys#update
               DELETE /surveys/:id(.:format)      surveys#destroy
```

See:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: That's really helpful.